# Missing required parameter for route?

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-routing

First of all i would like to say that my english are not so good and is my first time posting here , so excuse me if i did something wrong! Well i am starting practicing with Laravel and i am trying to create a url for users can like posts. my url and controller is right now this `Route::post('/post/{post}/like', [LikeController::class, 'postLike'])->name('post.like');` where post is the posts post that i am trying to pass through my form action attribute. Here is my form:

```
@props(['post'])

<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'card-footer d-flex justify-content-around']) }}>
    <form action= "{{ route('post.like' , $post) }}"  method="post" >
        @csrf
        <button>submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The post prop is actually the id of the post! I passed it as an argument on this component like this :`:post="$post->id" i have also tried with associative array without it be necessary if u have only one parameter to pass, but still didnt work!`{{ route('post.like' , ['post'=>$post]) }}```
if u wonder if the id is not actually passed into component , i tried {{ dd($post) }} and it printed it. My controller is this which it doesnt actually do anything right now. i am just trying to pass the id:

```
class LikeController extends Controller
{
    public function postLike(Post $post) {
        dd($post);
    }
}
```

After all this i am getting the error: **Missing required parameter for [Route: post.like] [URI: post/{post}/like] [Missing parameter: post]. (View: blog\resources\views\components\post\interaction.blade.php)**

i am having two days to find the problem and i am still trying this moment i am sending this.... I cant found where is the mistake! If u could help me would me much appreciated! Ty in advance

Comment: The error message does not match your code. Please edit your question to show the code that generates the error.

Comment: Maybe ```{{ route('post.like' , ['post'=>$post->id]) }}``` ??

Comment: Hello ! Thx for ur time and answers! My bad I didn't mention that! The post parameter inside component is actually the id of the post! I used :post="$post->id"  as an argument on this component! Sorry i mention this here!

Comment: It working only if i hard coded the url like this : ```<form action="/post/{{$post}}/like" method="POST">``` I am realy confuses why it doesnt work with the route helper.... it should !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Also, jesus its working if i do something like ```<form action="{{ route('post.like' , 2) }}" method="POST">``` by giving the integer id of the post without a parameter!!! So this works: ```<form action="{{ route('post.like' , 2) }}" method="POST">``` and this not:```<form action="{{ route('post.like' , $post) }}" method="POST">``` What the... is going on here! –

Answer (score 1):

Try this in web.php to see if the route model binding is working well to that point

```
Route::post('/post/{post}/like', function($post){
   dd($post);
})->name('post.like');
```

Comment: Hello! i tried it still ouputs the same error!!! I cant see why it doesnt work!! it should! i also tried this ```{{ dd(route('post.like', $post)) }} ``` to see if it generates the right ulr and it does it prints localhost::..../post/2/like ! i mean i raise hands on the air! First time i cant debugg an error in a project i am doing!!!